# overlapping rotated buttons - on click behind one comes to front

Tags: android, animation, button, overlap

I'm programmatically creating two overlapping buttons in a RelativeLayout. Both buttons have different angles so you can press each one. When I press the button on the bottom it comes to front. What should I do so that the button remains behind the other one?

Edit:
I forgot to say, that I'm turning the buttons with a RotationAnimation and fillAfter. Without the animation the button remains on the bottom. My min. api is 8, because of that i have to use the anomation.

Edit 2:
I'm throwing 78 cards randomly in a RelativeLayout. On that way I'm creating a pile of cards. When I click a card, which is under another card, it comes to front.

```
    ImageButton card;
    Random random = new Random();
    RotateAnimation cardRotation;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int angle = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<78;i++) {
        x = random.nextInt(fieldWidth + 1 - cardHeight - cardHeight / 4) + cardHeight / 4;
        y = random.nextInt(fieldHeight + 1 - cardHeight - cardHeight / 2) + cardHeight / 2;
        angle = random.nextInt(360 + 1);
        angle = random.nextInt(360 + 1);

        card = new ImageButton(this);
        card.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        card.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_back);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cardParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(cardWidth, cardHeight);
        cardParams.leftMargin = x;
        cardParams.topMargin = y;
        card.setLayoutParams(cardParams);

        cardRotation = new RotateAnimation(0, angle, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        cardRotation.setDuration(0);
        cardRotation.setFillAfter(true);
        card.startAnimation(cardRotation);

        card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cardClicked(v);
            }
        });

        cardField.addView(card);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the button at the back.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work because i use RotationAnimation. I forgot to say that.

Comment: Please add your code. That will make things clearer.

Comment: I have added it. I'm throwing 78 cards randomly in a RelativeLayout. On that way I'm creating a pile of cards. When I click a card, which is under another card, it comes to front.

Comment: So card.setFocusableOnTouchMode(false) isn't working?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? It can be tested easily then